# Make Git Bash open to root directory from custom link

Tags: windows, git, git-bash, rainmeter

I'm using rainmeter to make a custom dashboard for windows and ran into a problem making a custom start button for git bash needing it to open to my root directory.

The odd part is I have gitbash added to my windows taskbar and the target is..

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\sh.exe" --login -i
```

That opens to my user root.. MyName@MYNAME

But if I create a link in rainmeter using that same link it takes me to.. MyName@MYNAME /usr/bin

That makes zero sense to me. How can I make it open to my root?

Answer (score 0):

Try running this command.  It adds a line to the .bashrc file and that should cd you to root.

```
echo cd / >> ~/.bashrc
```

It should open your gitbash to root everytime you open the shell.

Comment: I get a sh.exe": alias: /: not found. When I start gitbash

Comment: There might be something useful at this stack overflow thread: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7017143/git-bash-how-to-default-to-other-directory-instead-of-home-directory)

Comment: Also some solutions here: [stackoverflow.com](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7671461/how-do-i-change-the-default-location-for-git-bash-in-windows)